# Matrix representation for Gupta-Bleuler creation/annihilation operators

Tags: gauge-theory, commutator

I am wondering what would be the closest analogue of the [matrix representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators#Matrix_representation) for the creation and annihilation operators arising in Gupta-Bleuler formalism, which are defined by
$$
[a,a^\dagger] = -1 \,,\\
a|0\rangle = 0 \, ,\\
a^\dagger |0\rangle = |1\rangle \, .
$$
The first line suggests starting with the usual CCR and redefining $a\leftrightarrow a^\dagger$, but this would not work in the basis built upon $|0\rangle$ defined by the second condition.

**UPDATE** (skip part can be skipped, the answer is presented below).

Attaching my "failed naive attempt" to construct matrices for $a$ and $a^\dagger$. This attempt contains a mistake, which is highly non-trivial to find without basic familiarity with indefinite norm vector spaces such as those one encounters in special relativity. See the answer below.

[image: As Gupta-Bleuler formalism leads to non-unitarities, some pathologies should clearly arise here.]

Comment: Can you give references where you find this commutator?

Comment: See, for example, section 2.2 [here](https://www.scielo.br/j/bjp/a/XPg4mPKNb5VHfNstPPBJ8cm/?lang=en).

Answer (score 0):

A nice discussion can be found [here](https://cdnsciencepub.com/doi/10.1139/p99-018).
In what follows the adjoint of $a$ will be denoted by $a^\ddagger$.

From the conditions in the question one immediately derives:
$$
a|1\rangle = a a^\ddagger|0\rangle = (a^\ddagger a-1) |0\rangle = -|0\rangle.
$$
More generally, one obtains:
$$
a|n\rangle = -n |n-1\rangle \, ,\\
a^\ddagger|n\rangle = \sqrt{n+1} |n+1\rangle \, .
$$

Therefore, the matrix representations of the Gupta-Bleuler operators are:
$$
a = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\sqrt{1} & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & -\sqrt{2} & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -\sqrt{3} & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\ddots \\
\end{pmatrix}
\,,\quad
a^\ddagger = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
\sqrt{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 &  \ldots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\ddots \\
\end{pmatrix}\, ,
$$
wherefrom we immediately realize that the definition of adjoint has to differ from the usual one:
$$a^\ddagger \equiv -a^\dagger \, . $$

Normalizing the states:
$$
\langle 1|1\rangle
=\langle 0|aa^\ddagger|0\rangle
=\langle 0|(a^\ddagger a-1)|0\rangle
= -1 \, ,\\
\langle 2|2\rangle
=\mathcal{N}_2^2\langle 1|aa^\ddagger|1\rangle
=\mathcal{N}_2^2\langle 1|(a^\ddagger a-1)|1\rangle
= 2\mathcal{N}_2^2 \, ,\\
\ldots
$$
Thus we arrive at
$$
|n\rangle = (-1)^n \dfrac{(a^\ddagger)^n}{\sqrt{n}}|0\rangle\,.
$$
The metric (lower indices!) is then given by
$$
M_{nm} = \langle n | m \rangle = \delta_{n,m} (-1)^n \, .
$$

**Bonus: the mistakes in the naive solution above.**

Matrix representations of creation and annihilation operators correspond to $(a)^i{}_j$ and $(a^\ddagger)^i{}_j$ indices. Therefore,
$$
\langle 1 | a^\ddagger | 0 \rangle = -1 \neq (a^\ddagger)^1{}_0 \, .
$$
Instead, similarly to the definition of the metric above,
$$
(a^\ddagger)_{10} = \langle 1 | a^\ddagger | 0 \rangle = -1 \, ,
$$
while
$$
(a^\ddagger)^1{}_{0} = M^{11} (a^\ddagger)_{10} = 1 \, .
$$